# drop menu navigation in css using unordered lists

Tags: html, css

I've been at this for a few weeks now. I pretty much copied direct from my first project which was a recipe center. Below I'll paste my style sheet and my nav file for everyone to view and try and help me figure out why the drop menu doesn't appear when you hover over the parent list item.

nav.css

```css
/* rules for navigation menu */


/* ======================================================== */

ul#nav,
ul.drop,
ul.toss {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #f2f1f0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul.drop {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  /* for debugging purposes */
  width: 110px;
  background: forestgreen;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.toss {
  width: 110px;
  background: forestgreen;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

ul#nav li {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  /* for debugging purposes */
  height: 20px;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

ul#nav a {
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f2f1f0;
  background: none;
}

ul#nav a:hover {
  background: darkseagreen;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f2f1f0;
}

ul#nav .drop li {}

ul#nav li:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

ul#nav .drop a {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

ul#nav .toss a {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#nav li:hover>a {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav ul.drop li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav ul.toss li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav ul.drop {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul#nav ul.toss {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 95px;
}

ul#nav li.hover .drop {
  display: block;
}

ul#nav .drop li:hover .toss {
  display: block;
}


/*    rules for navigation menu END */


/* ==================================== */
```

nav.inc.php

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?card=About">About</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?card=Contact">Contact</a></li>

<li>Projects 
    <ul class="drop">
        <li>Recipe Center</li>
        <li>Store</li>
        <li>Admin</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following part of your css like so:

```
ul#nav li.hover .drop {
  display: block;
}
```

It needs to have a colon instead of a period between `li` and `hover` right now it is acting like hover is a class instead of the hover action.  So it should look like the following:

```
ul#nav li:hover .drop {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a revised snippet:

```css
/* rules for navigation menu */


/* ======================================================== */

ul#nav,
ul.drop,
ul.toss {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #f2f1f0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul.drop {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  /* for debugging purposes */
  width: 110px;
  background: forestgreen;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

ul.toss {
  width: 110px;
  background: forestgreen;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

ul#nav li {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  /* for debugging purposes */
  height: 20px;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

ul#nav a {
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f2f1f0;
  background: none;
}

ul#nav a:hover {
  background: darkseagreen;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f2f1f0;
}

ul#nav .drop li {}

ul#nav li:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

ul#nav .drop a {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

ul#nav .toss a {
  padding: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#nav li:hover>a {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav ul.drop li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav ul.toss li:hover a:hover {
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

ul#nav ul.drop {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul#nav ul.toss {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 95px;
}

ul#nav li:hover .drop {
  display: block;
}

ul#nav .drop li:hover .toss {
  display: block;
}


/*    rules for navigation menu END */


/* ==================================== */
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?card=About">About</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?card=Contact">Contact</a></li>

<li>Projects 
    <ul class="drop">
        <li>Recipe Center</li>
        <li>Store</li>
        <li>Admin</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
```